# Backup Azure blob storage in line with SQL Azure DB

Tags: windows, azure, storage, azure-sql-database

It is recommended that we store document information in blob storage. In our case the blob storage is related to the SQL Azure data, is the facility available to back up the blob storage in sync with the SQL Azure data ? What I don't want to see is a point in time restore of the SQL Azure data only to find we don't have the same snapshot of the blob data at that time :(

Does anyone know what is available

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue you have to solve. But there is no automated way to keep in sync BLOB and Azure SQL Database Data. You have to do manage this yourself. And here is not just about blob snapshots. How about your updated DB record refers to a new blob. What happens with the old one ?! This is all business rules to apply at application level. And you have to question yourself to what degree you want that backup of Blobs.

[Here is an interesting blog post on Azure SQL and Storage backup](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/01/azure-will-save-you-from-unexpected_28.html). But again - there is no service that will keep for you in sync data between SQL DB and Azure Storage.